# std::copy from a range into itself

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

This might be a silly question and the answer may simply be "Because," but I'm curious so here it goes.  Suppose I want to copy the final elements of an `std::vector` to the front without regard to what happens elsewhere.  I can do this with a simple function call

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> v;
.
.
.
std::copy(v.begin() + N, v.end(), v.begin());
```

What I find surprising is that the standard seems to brand this undefined behavior if `N == 0` (unless `v.empty()`, I suppose).  Since even a naive implementation of `std::copy` won't have problems in that case (and in fact yield a NOP), why is the standard so strict?

Comment: Well yes, but in the general case I understand why.  I don't understand the `N == 0` rationale.

Comment: A copy constructor that doesn't properly handle self-copy is simply broken, IMO.  I don't see why the STL should be limited due to such a possibility, though I certainly can't rule out that that's the motivation.

Comment: That's actually a good question and cannot think of any reason that the issue with self-copying. However this can be solved relatively easy.

Comment: Yes, any copy-and-swap implementation of `operator=` should do it.

Comment: Most likely because this can be solved at call-side so easily that no one will bother writing a proposal for that which would include proving that the extra check in `std::copy` has no (significant) extra cost.

Comment: As an easy reason, making it defined behavior adds verbage, and doesn't really make the function worse.  Your copy (with `N==0`) if they did define it would be a complete waste of time.  They could add "except if the range equals itself, in which case the copy call is a noop", but now we force implementations to test for that (wastefully when the caller *knows* it isn't a self-copy, because who does that?).

Comment: What's wrong with making a copy over the same range valid? Wasteful, but not undefined. Surely that is no worse.

Comment: @NeilKirk Then you couldn't use `memcpy` for trivial types, since `memcpy(v.data(), v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(int))` is also UB