# Copying classes between ranges that might overlap

Tags: c++

In C, we have the functions `memcpy` and `memmove` to efficiently copy data around.  The former yields undefined behavior if the source and destination regions overlap, but the latter is guaranteed to deal with that "as expected," presumably by noticing the direction of overlap and (if necessary) choosing a different algorithm.

The above functions are available in C++ (as `std::memcpy` and `std::memmove`), of course, but they don't really work with non-trivial `class`es.  Instead, we get `std::copy` and `std::copy_backward`.  Each of these works if the source and destination ranges don't overlap; moreover, each is guaranteed to work for one "direction" of overlap.

**What can we use if we want to copy from one region to another and we don't know at compile-time if the ranges may overlap or in what direction that overlap may occur?**  It doesn't seem that we have an option.  For general `iterator`s it may be difficult to determine if ranges overlap, so I understand why no solution is provided in that case, but **what about when we're dealing with pointers?**  Ideally, there'd be a function like:

```
template<class T>
T * copy_either_direction(const T * inputBegin, const T * inputEnd, T * outputBegin) {
    if ("outputBegin ∈ [inputBegin, inputEnd)") {
        outputBegin += (inputEnd - inputBegin);
        std::copy_backward(inputBegin, inputEnd, outputBegin);
        return outputBegin;
    } else {
        return std::copy(inputBegin, inputEnd, outputBegin);
    }
}
```

(A similar function with `T *` replaced with `std::vector<T>::iterator` would also be nice.  Even better would be if this were guaranteed to work if `inputBegin == outputBegin`, but that's [a separate gripe of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940331/stdcopy-from-a-range-into-itself).)

Unfortunately, I don't see a sensible way to write the condition in the `if` statement, as comparing pointers into separate blocks of memory often yields undefined behavior.  On the other hand, the implementation clearly has its own way to do this, as `std::memmove` inherently requires one.  Thus, any implementation *could* provide such a function, thereby filling a need that the programmer simply *can't*.  Since `std::memmove` was considered useful, why not `copy_either_direction`?  Is there a solution I'm missing?

Comment: Since classes can contain non-POD types like `std::string` or `std::vector`, are you considering deep moving?

Comment: I'm considering running whatever copy function the class uses.

Comment: Can you give an example where the region may overlap?  In order to get overlapping regions, you would need to do some unsafe type casting.  The `memmove` is a low level function only concerned with moving contents of memory without regards to any high level constructs.   The higher level `std::copy` algorithms call constructors which improves the safety but reduces the efficiency.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to copy elements from one array to an offset into another array that _may_ be the same array.

Comment: `std::copy` won't work -- it only works if the ranges are disjoint or if we're copying to "lower" addresses.  What if I don't know that that will always be the case?

Comment: A few responders are not understanding the question, maybe reword it as "how do I move objects between overlapping ranges" without having memmove in the title

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the suggestion.  When I mentioned `std::memmove` in the title I was primarily thinking about its ability to handle overlapping regions.  Hopefully the new title is clearer.

Comment: Maybe a code example would help too

Answer (score 0):

`memmove` works because it traffics in pointers to contiguous bytes, so the ranges of the two blocks to be copied are well defined. `copy` and `move` take iterators that don't necessarily point at contiguous ranges. For example, a list iterator can jump around in memory; there's no range that the code can look at, and no meaningful notion of overlap.

Comment: I agree in general, but what if the `iterator`s are actually raw pointers (or, perhaps, `std::vector::iterator`s for which comparisons may also be reasonable [for the implementation])?

Comment: Suppose `it1, it2, it3` are iterators into the same `std::list` Is it correct to say `std::copy(it1, it2, it3);` ?    (If you say "I don't know" then OP's question is: how do we make sure this is correct)

Comment: @M.M, I'm not convinced that there _can_ be a simple solution for `std::list`s.  I think there _should_ be a solution for arrays (and maybe `std::vector`s and `std::array`s).

Comment: For vector I'm imagining some combination of `<` and `>` operators and thereby selecting either `copy` or `copy_backward` , but general input iterators don't have that option. Maybe there is really no solution other than to also track the overlappy-ness (?) of the ranges as a part of whatever algorithm you are using to select the ranges in the first place

Comment: @M.M, I agree that using `<` and `>` "should" work for `std::vector`.  The trouble is that I don't think we're allowed to compare `iterator`s into different containers using those operators, even if they're both of the same type.  (For pointers into different arrays the comparisons would certainly be disallowed.)  The implementation, on the other hand, is allowed to do whatever it wants, and clearly it has _some_ way of implementing the desired check in `std::memmove`.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen you'd have to know in advance whether they were iterators into the same container or not

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that `std::less` is specialized for pointers in a way that provides a total order, presumably to allow one to store pointers in `std::set`s and related `class`es.  Assuming that this must agree with the standard ordering whenever the latter is defined, I think the following will work:

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
T * copy_either_direction(const T * inputBegin, const T * inputEnd, T * outputBegin) {
    if (std::less<const T *>()(inputBegin, outputBegin)) {
        outputBegin += (inputEnd - inputBegin);
        std::copy_backward(inputBegin, inputEnd, outputBegin);
        return outputBegin;
    } else {
        return std::copy(inputBegin, inputEnd, outputBegin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> What can we use if we want to copy from one region to another and we don't know at compile-time if the ranges may overlap or in what direction that overlap may occur?

This is not a logically consistent concept.

After a copy operation, you will have two objects. And each object is defined by a separate and *distinct* region of memory. You cannot have objects which overlap in this way (you can have subobjects, but an object type cannot be its own subobject). And therefore, it is impossible to copy an object on top of part of itself.

To *move* an object on top of itself is *also* not logically consistent. Why? Because moving is a fiction in C++; after the move, you *still* have two perfectly functional objects. A move operation is merely a destructive copy, one that steals resources owned by the other object. It is *still there*, and it is still a viable object.

And since an object cannot overlap with another object, it is again impossible.

Trivially copyable types get around this because they are just blocks of bits, with no destructors or specialized copy operations. So their lifetime is not as rigid as that of others. A non-trivially copyable type cannot do this because:

> The experience with memmove suggests that there could be a solution in this case (and perhaps also for iterators into contiguous containers).

This is neither possible nor generally desirable for types which are not trivially copyable in C++.

The rules for trivial copyability are that the type has no non-trivial copy/move constructors/assignment operators, as well as no non-trivial destructor. A trivial copy/move constructor/assignment is nothing more than a memcpy, and a trivial destructor does nothing. And therefore, these rules effectively ensures that the type is nothing more than a "block of bits". And one "block of bits" is no different from another, so copying it via `memmove` is a legal construct.

If a type has a real destructor, then the type is maintaining some sort of invariant that requires actual effort to maintain. It may free up a pointer or release a file handle or whatever. Given that, it makes no sense to copy the bits, because now you have *two* objects that reference the same pointer/file handle. That's a bad thing to do, because the class will generally want to control how that gets handled.

There is no way to solve this problem *without* the class itself being involved in the copy operation. Different class have *different* behavior with respect to managing their internals. Indeed, that is *the entire purpose* of objects having copy constructors and assignment operators. So that a class can decide for itself how to maintain the sanity of its own state.

And it doesn't even have to be a pointer or file handle. Maybe each class instance has a unique identifier; such a value is generated at construction time, and it *never* gets copied (new copies get new values). For you to violate such a restriction with `memmove` leaves your program in an indeterminate state, because you will have code that expects such identifiers to be unique.

That's why `memmove`ing for non-trivially copyable types yields undefined behavior.

Comment: I think this misses the point of the question,  he is not asking to literally `memmove` an object  , rather, he wants to use the builtin assignment operator and move the objects properly

Comment: I _want_ to run the `class`'s copy function, using it to copy elements (one at a time) from one series of addresses to another.  I cannot use `std::memmove` since, as you note, it will just copy a block of bits which may not be what is required.  I cannot use `std::copy` or `std::copy_backward` since each requires particular relationships between the source and destination ranges which may not be guaranteed at compile-time.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: I added more information which explains why what you want is impossible.

Comment: @NicolBolas your answer still seems to be talking about overlapping objects (which is not what OP is asking about)

Comment: I agree that objects cannot overlap, but two regions of objects certainly can.  For example, suppose I have the array `T arr[10]` and want to copy elements `arr[5]`, `arr[6]`, and `arr[7]` to positions 4, 5, and 6 (respectively) in `arr`.  In this precise case I could use `std::copy` but only because I _know_ how the ranges overlap.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: If your question has nothing to do with `memmove` (and it doesn't seem to), why did you spend the first two paragraphs talking about it? Maybe you should restate your question to focus specifically on that particular case. Namely, wanting to copy contiguous ranges of objects to another contiguous range, where the ranges may overlap without knowing whether or how they overlap.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'll think about rephrasing.  My primary reason for bringing up `std::memmove` was that, other than that it copies bitwise rather than through the copy-assignment operator, it basically has my desired semantics and somehow determines overlap in a well-defined way that seems unavailable to programmers.